# Minecraft Vanilla server - Test if a player is lagging?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was just wondering if there was a way I could test if a player is having lag issues while playing. This is a very important feature, because players that are lagging are susceptible to a false ban by the command block anticheat. I am trying things out such as setting their `Alive` score to 0, and adding 1 to it every tick, I've also tried this with the `Alive` objective being `stat.timeSinceLastDeath`

I thought this would work, because when a the player/server is lagging, the scores don't properly add/set. (not just client side, also server side) I guess the real question is: **How can I test if a player's objective score stops incrementing?** Because, in theory, if the player's score stops incrementing, then they or the server are lagging.

Comment: @Ben He wants vanilla, not modded (Bukkit, Spigot etc.)

Comment: @nelson2tm missed that (not sure how). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i now, the scoreboard is completly server side. So you cant check if the player is lagging.

You can see how good the ping of a player is by pressing tab.

There is a way seeing the exact ping of a player is kind of hard:

1. Look into the server console a search for the ip of the player

> [time] [Server thread/INFO]: player[/**127.0.0.1**:52288] logged in

2. Once you have ping the player by typing `ping [ip]` (on windows)

> 127.0.0.1: Bytes=32 Time<**1ms** TTL=128

Hope it helped a little bit.

Comment: That would still get lots of false positives on university people, as usually all the people from 1 university share the same ip address, and the path between the people, and the university router is complex